# path of UIImage for figure inside png

Tags: iphone, cocoa

i have png, which  have clear background with difficult figure inside, like animal. For me is necessary to get path of this figure exactly, to draw it on background image. 
Can u suggest any way to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Use png alpha channel to create a mask for the background image. There is a more detailed discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126276/how-to-convert-uiimage-cgimagerefs-alpha-channel-to-mask).

Comment: can u explain more, with example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126276/how-to-convert-uiimage-cgimagerefs-alpha-channel-to-mask